# Async with loop function task list node js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Hello i am using `async parallel` in my code for practice code

```
var tasklist = [],tempjson={};
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {
   tempjson.data = 'i is' + i;
   for(var j = 0; j < 20; j++){
      tasklist.push(doSomething(tempjson,j));
   }
}
 async.parallel(taskList, function(err, data) {
       console.log(data);
 });

function doSomething(params,j){
       params.data2 = 'j value is'+ j
       return callback(null,params)
}
```

want to do something like that but i am getting error that callback is undefined  can somebody help me what is wrong with code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `callback` as a argument to the function `doSomething`.

Just add the callback argument like

```
function doSomething(params,j){
     return function(callback){
       params.data2 = 'j value is'+ j
       return callback(null,params)
     }   

}
```

This will solve the problem!!

Comment: getting error stack: 'TypeError: callback is not a function\n

Comment: Updated the answer!!, Sorry my bad

Comment: thax bro for help

Answer (score 1):

> ReferenceError: callback is not defined

This is because you're not passing `callback` to `doSomething()`. As per [docs](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel), We need to pass callback to the function.

Also, there is a typo in your code. It is `tasklist` and not `taskList`

Fixing this,

```
  var tasklist = [], tempjson = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tempjson.data = 'i is' + i;
    for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
      tasklist.push(function (callback) {
        doSomething(tempjson, j, callback);
      }); // Array of task as per docs
    }
  }
  async.parallel(tasklist, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

  function doSomething(params, j, callback) { // passing callback as per docs
    params.data2 = 'j value is' + j;
    return callback(null, params)
  }
```

This will log

> [ { data: 'i is9', data2: 'j value is20' },
>     { data: 'i is9', data2: 'j value is20' },
>     ... ... 100 more items ]